# PHP ftp connection to Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

Hi I have been struggling on this for one day. My ftp connection through putty is working file where i am passing public DNS and then upload .pem key for password. But when i am trying to do so through PHP it is not able to connect. Any help would be highly appreciated.
My PHP Code is:

```
$server='AMAZON EC2 Public DNS';
$username='root';
$password='**i copy pasted key from .pem file**';

try {

    $con = ftp_connect($server);
    ftp_pasv($con, true);
    if (false === $con) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }

    $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
    if (true === $loggedIn) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
    }


    ftp_close($con);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use AWS SDK for PHP: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/index.html

Comment: I am trying this. Will it be useful for FTP connection?

Comment: @user2131695 How is FTP configured on your instance?

Comment: Regarding FTP Configuration i did not do any thing. Do i need to configure something on instance if i want to use through PHP? FYI putty is working from my local system

Comment: @user2131695 Depends on what you want to do with FTP connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP's FTP isn't working on Amazon linux EC2 instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424125/phps-ftp-isnt-working-on-amazon-linux-ec2-instance)

Comment: It seems Mr Uri Agassi has not seen my code. I have taken the reference from that Question's Answers. As you may see `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);` line in my code. But still i am facing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your effort. I had solved this using [SSH Connection to Amazon Ec2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ftp_server = 'your_amazon_instance_url';
$ftp_user_name = 'username';
$ftp_user_pass = 'password for ftp instance for user';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br/>";
}
```